# Remove ECS task for forensic analysis

Tags: amazon-ecs

I use Amazon ECS for my services. ECS autoregisters the containers with the ELB. That is all fine.
However if one of my application gets into a failure mode I want to take it out of the ELB but keep it running so I can do forensic on it.
If I remove it from the ELB manually then ECS will just add it back in.

The AutoScaling group has a "standby" state. I guess it is something similar I am looking for in ECS.

Is that possible somehow?

Comment: You could just cause it to fail the health check somehow, that would cause it to go have no requests would be sent to it.

Comment: That does not help. When ECS detects an unhealthy instance it will stop the task and start a new one. So the task will be gone and I can not connect to the running instance.

Comment: You said instance not task. There's no way to take a task out of service with ECS configured the way it is without it being stopped and started somewhere else. Perhaps you should manage docker yourself if this is your requirement as it does not fit in the ECS scope

Comment: Thanks. That is also what I figured. I guess this is still a valid answer even if it is not what I hoped for. Maybe ECS will add this someday.